# Disable dictionary in Tesseract

Tags: command-line, tesseract

How can I disable dictionary corrections when running Tesseract for English language?

I'm currently running tesseract as a child process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to set these variables (put them in a config file) to false:

```
load_system_dawg 
load_freq_dawg
load_punc_dawg
load_number_dawg
load_unambig_dawg
load_bigram_dawg
load_fixed_length_dawgs
```

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/tesseract-ocr/Disable$20dictionary$20in$20Tesseract/tesseract-ocr/5nvIo1DJxHE/f3gBi2pTKykJ

Also read [How to increase the trust in/strength of the dictionary?](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/FAQ#how-to-increase-the-trust-instrength-of-the-dictionary) in the FAQ. From it:

> For tesseract-ocr < 3.01 try upping NON_WERD and GARBAGE_STRING in dict/permute.cpp to maybe 3 or even 5.
>
> For tesseract-ocr >= 3.01 try increasing the variables **language_model_penalty_non_freq_dict_word** and **language_model_penalty_non_dict_word** in a config file. By default they are 0.1 and 0.15 respectively.