# Disable dictionary-assisted OCR in tesseract C++ API

Tags: c++, api, ocr, tesseract

I have an application where technical datasheets are OCR'd using the tesseract API. I initialize it like this:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;
tess.Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY);
```

However, even after using custom whitelists like this

```
tess.SetVariable("tessedit_char_blacklist", "");
tess.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", myWhitelist);
```

some datasheet entries are recognized wrongly, for example `PA3` is recognized as `FAB`.

How can I disable the dictionary-assisted OCR, i.e. . In order to not affect other tools I don't want to modify global config files if possible.

*Note*: This is *not* a duplicate of [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364662/disable-dictionary-in-tesseract) because said question explicitly asks for the command-line tool while I explicitly ask for the tesseract API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in following way

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng"))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
    exit(1);
}

if(!api->SetVariable("tessedit_enable_doc_dict", "0"))
{
    cout << "Unable to enable dictionary" << endl;
}
```

Simply pass `"tessedit_enable_doc_dict"` as a parameter to `SetVariable` function and it's corresponding boolean value.

I found it in `tesseractclass.h` https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/a00736_source.html header file(line 839) and i guess best way to find correct parameters is by looking at the values defined at it(header file corresponding to your version. mine is 3.04).
I tried few i found on internet before but didn't work. This was the working configuration to me.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. As I've not really continued with my Tesseract problem, I haven't really investigated if my answer our your answer is the better way of approaching the issue. However, looking back, I think its clear that `tessedit_enable_doc_dict` is the way to go, so I'm going to finally accept your answer :-)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply set the penalties to zero:

```
tess.SetVariable("segment_penalty_garbage", "0");
tess.SetVariable("segment_penalty_dict_nonword", "0");
tess.SetVariable("segment_penalty_dict_frequent_word", "0");
tess.SetVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_ok", "0");
tess.SetVariable("segment_penalty_dict_case_bad", "0");
```

While the dictionary still stays active, this approach basically tells the algorithm that a dictionary-hit (also includes bad punctuation etc) is no better than a non-dictionary hit.

See [the `dict.cpp` source code](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/dict/dict.cpp) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn of dictionaries only during [initialization of API](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ControlParams#init-only). See [tesseract-ocr API example in C++ of changing init parameters](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ControlParams#init-only) for tesseract 3.02.

Comment: So you mean if I set `load_system_dawg` = 0, the dictionary will not apply?

Comment: No exactly. If you use during tesseract initialization `load_system_dawg = 0` "system" dictionary will not be loaded. If you would like to use it later you will need to initialize tesseract once again.