# Initialize tesseract without any external resources (languages/dictionaries)

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I am currently writing a C++ program that should read hex data from JPEG images. I have to compile it into one **single** windows executable **without any external resources** (like the "tessdata" directory or config files). As I am not reading any words or sentences, I don't need any dictionaries or languages.

My problem is now that I could not find a way to initialize the API without any language files. Every example uses something like this:

```
tesseract::TessBaseAPI api;
if (api.Init(NULL, "eng")) {
    // error handling
    return -1;
}
// do stuff
```

I also found that I can call the init function without language argument and with `OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY`:

```
if(api.Init(NULL, NULL, tesseract::OcrEngineMode::OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY)) {
    // ...
}
```

This *should* disable the language/dictionary, but `NULL` just defaults to "eng". It seems like tesseract still wants a language file to initialize and will disable it afterwards.

This also seems to be the case for any other solutions I found so far: I always need .traineddata files to initialize the api and can [disable them afterwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005215/disable-dictionary-assisted-ocr-in-tesseract-c-api/34262468) or using [config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364662/disable-dictionary-in-tesseract).

My question is now:
Is there any way to initialize the tesseract API in C++ using just the executable and no other resource files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Tesseract always needs some language (default is `eng`) + `osd` (`.traineddata`) files. Without language data file tesseract is useless.

Your post seems that you made several wrong assumptions (e.g. about `OEM_TESSERACT_ONLY`), so maybe if you describe what you try to achieve with tesseract you can get better advice.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Like I said, I have some JPEG files with hex data printed on them and want to read them via OCR. If tesseract always needs those resources I might use another OCR library or just embed the files in the exe and extract them to a temporary directory.

Comment: Without traineddata (trained OCR models a.k.a language data in case of tesseract) you are not able to run any OCR. Putting everything info one file will soon become bottleneck for further progress