# disable dictionnary in tesseract 4.0 with command line

Tags: windows, command-line, tesseract

i'm using tesseract command line in windows, how can i disable dictionary when running tesseract? i'm using tesseract 4.00.00alpha

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable dictionary in Tesseract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364662/disable-dictionary-in-tesseract)

Comment: I'm not an expert, but reading the [manual](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc) it looks like the only way is through the *configfile*, and that's what the answer to the other question suggests. How is your question different?