# generating eng.traineddata for tesseract 3.03 without using wordlist

Tags: python-2.7, tesseract

I'm working on a processing image project. what I have to do is to extract text from image, I'm actually using a python wrapper for tesseract 3.03 on windows and I have downloaded the .traineddata files for many languages(english,frensh,...).the problem is tha I read somewhere that tesseract try to detect words using the wordlist file after detecting separated characters. My question is how to generate the .traineddata files without using wordlist because I want tesseract to return the sentence detected without verifying words

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack `.traineddata` file, replace the dictionary components with empty ones, and repack. Or you can simply disable the dictionary.

[Disable dictionary in Tesseract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364662/disable-dictionary-in-tesseract)

Comment: thank you so much, I will try that and provide a feed back

Comment: I have done a quick search, I understood that .traineddata file is generated by crunching the files 

tessdata/eng.config
tessdata/eng.unicharset
tessdata/eng.unicharambigs
tessdata/eng.inttemp
tessdata/eng.pffmtable
tessdata/eng.normproto
tessdata/eng.punc-dawg
tessdata/eng.word-dawg
tessdata/eng.number-dawg
tessdata/eng.freq-dawg

and as you said I will replace

tessdata/eng.punc-dawg
tessdata/eng.word-dawg
tessdata/eng.number-dawg
tessdata/eng.freq-dawg

by empty ones.The problem now is where to find the other files for tesseract 3.02

Comment: I'm just looking for a unicharset file and the corresponding inttemp, pffmtable, normproto for english , tesseract 3.02

Comment: Check the [doc](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/combine_tessdata.1.asc) on `combine_tessdata` to unpack the `.traineddata` file.